# where should i put the partial js and css file in flask project

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

i have a flask project and use jinja2 template engine, in template part: i make a base.html like this:

```
    {%- block styles %}
        {% include 'static_partial/style.html' %}
    {%- endblock styles %}

<body{% block body_attribs %}{% endblock body_attribs %}>
{% block body -%}
    <div class="container">
    {% block navbar %}
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    {%- endblock navbar %}

    {% block scripts %}
        {% include 'static_partial/script.html' %}
    {%- endblock scripts %}
    </div>
{%- endblock body %}
</body>
{%- endblock html %}
</html>
```

i import js and css files in a partial directory, and the navbar.html also.

and in navbar.html, i have some css and js definition in itself, where should i put the narbar.html css and js definition? if i put it in navbar.html, it will cause error because the js need to load some js file from base.html first, it confused me for a long time....

the project structure is like this:

```
├── station
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── py
```

my scripts.html is like this:

```
<!-- jQuery2 -->
        <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- BootStrap Plugins -->
        <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Global JS -->
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/global.js')}}"></script>
```

and then i include this file in my base.html

Comment: In a Flask project, all styles and javascript usually lives in the ./static folder. Are you using the static folder? Can you share your current folder structure?

Comment: @SinanGuclu i just update my questions

Comment: Do you also include the scripts.html partial in the header.html partial?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, you can add another js file for your navbar's JavaScript under `assets/js` ie `navbar.js`.

The add it as another script tag in `scripts.html`:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/navbar.js')}}"></script>
```